# Are there any additional belief systems regarding The Force, other than Light, Dark and Grey?

Tags: star-wars, the-force

That I know of, there is the [Light](http://s3.amazonaws.com/rapgenius/1345598281_Episode_4_Luke_Skywalker_1.jpg), the [Dark](http://media.boingboing.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/darth-vader-face.jpeg) and the [Grey](http://orig09.deviantart.net/227b/f/2011/062/9/d/jolee_bindo_by_otisframpton-d3au8p1.jpg).

You make a concious decision which of these paths to follow, but are there any additional belief systems someone could adhere to if they were force users?

Black, white and grey pretty much covers everything in the spectrum I suppose but the expanded universe is so massive, I'm wondering if anyone has found another way.

Comment: *"Black, white and grey pretty much covers everything in the spectrum.."*  What about 'rainbow'?  ;)

Comment: @AndrewThompson that's the kind of _outside the box_ thinking I like to see!!

Comment: There's about a dozen on Wookiepedia.  They intersect in different ways that I'm not confident in detangling (for example, I think the Living Force is either an alternate name for the Light side, or a superset of the Light and Dark.  Likewise, the Potentium sounds related to the Light side to me, but which Wookiepedia says "is not to be confused with the Unifying Force")

Comment: They're also not all in one place on Wookiepedia; "[Force philosophies](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Force_philosophies)", "[Alternate views of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Force#Alternate_views_on_the_Force)", and "[Four aspects of the Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/The_Force#Four_aspects_of_the_Force)" are the ones I know of

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. Going with the color motif, [Aing-Tii](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Aing-Tii) believed that there's no dark or light side, just a rainbow of colors of the Force

Some Jedi/Sith actually subscribed to a system known as [Unifying Force](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Unifying_Force), which held that there's no light or dark side, just a single Force (Ironically, according to later C-canon, Emperor Palpatine held this view).

Comment: In line with the "[good and evil are just words](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/WhatIsEvil)" trope...

Comment: The Jedi Academy Training Manual is incorrect on this point ( as is Wookieepedia, which faithfully reproduces the JATM's error ). The term "the unifying Force" does *not*, in its true definition, refer to the erroneous belief that the Force does not have sides. It refers not to a philosophy but to a part or aspect of the Force, something that is now more commonly known as the Cosmic Force, which coexists with the living Force and its sides. For an example of the term unifying Force being used as intended, see Terry Brooks' Phantom Menace novelization, page 141 of the paperback edition.

Answer (score 0):

And let us not forget the [White Current](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/White_Current), studied by the Fallanassi.

Comment: Could you add a bit more detail to your post to improve its quality?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are too many beliefs to count.  The Light/Dark (gray) is oversimplification by the Jedi and Sith that are too set in their traditions to think clearly.  Many cultures are referenced in the old Expanded Universe for having their own Force traditions.  A simple case is the Voss, and their view that the Force is, and that is it.

Just look at all the religions and spiritual paths here on Earth.  Most of them have a focus on what may be thought of as the Light side, but politics and other human flaws bring them into conflict.

Answer (score 0):

As of *The Force Awakens*, there is a religion known as the Church of the Force. They were the villagers that were wiped out at the beginning of the movie. Look to Wookieepedia or the Visual Dictionary for more information.

Comment: If you post some excerpts from the Visual Dictionary, you'll get points!